How connect multi slave to raspberry pi 3b in I2C with python?
I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and three TSL2561 modules. How to receive data simultaneously?
The TSL2561 has 5 pins.
1-GND
2-VCC
3-SDA
4-SCL
5-INT
Library: sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-tsl2561
lux - The computed light lux value measured by the sensor.
broadband - The broadband channel value.
infrared - The infrared channel value.
luminosity - A 2-tuple of broadband and infrared channel values.

import time
import board
import busio
import adafruit_tsl2561
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

tsl = adafruit_tsl2561.TSL2561(i2c)

print("Chip ID = {}".format(tsl.chip_id))
print("Enabled = {}".format(tsl.enabled))
print("Gain = {}".format(tsl.gain))
print("Integration time = {}".format(tsl.integration_time))

print("Configuring TSL2561...")
tsl.enabled = True
time.sleep(1)

# Set gain 0=1x, 1=16x
tsl.gain = 0

# Set integration time (0=13.7ms, 1=101ms, 2=402ms, or 3=manual)
tsl.integration_time = 1

print("Getting readings...")

# Get raw (luminosity) readings individually
broadband = tsl.broadband
infrared = tsl.infrared

# Get raw (luminosity) readings using tuple unpacking
# broadband, infrared = tsl.luminosity

# Get computed lux value (tsl.lux can return None or a float)
lux = tsl.lux

# Print results
print("Enabled = {}".format(tsl.enabled))
print("Gain = {}".format(tsl.gain))
print("Integration time = {}".format(tsl.integration_time))
print("Broadband = {}".format(broadband))
print("Infrared = {}".format(infrared))
if lux is not None:
    print("Lux = {}".format(lux))
else:
    print("Lux value is None. Possible sensor underrange or overrange.")

tsl.enabled = False


I write code for one tsl2561, but it doesn't work for three.

The TSL2561 has 5 pins it has 6 pins How to receive data simultaneously ? Connect them over 3 different i2c lines.

I use the module tsl2561. How do I do that you give?

You connected the wrong way. Pin 1 is Positive. Pin 9 is Negative, Pin 3 is SDA,, and PIn 5 is SCL. The INT is unconnected.
